# Как умножить на 100 метки оси y в plot() в R

Tags: r

Что нужно ввести сюда

```
plot (object, las=1, col=1, lwd=2)
```

чтобы числа (метки, label) на оси ординат умножились на 100 (не на 100%, а именно на 100)?

Comment: `?axis` параметр `labels`.

Answer (score 1):

```r
x <- 1:10
plot(x, las = 1, col = 1, lwd = 2, axes = FALSE)
axis(side = 1, at = x, labels = as.character(x * 100))
axis(side = 2, at = seq(min(x), max(x), by = 2))
```

Того же результата можно добавить с помощью пакет `ggplot2`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
    x = 1:10,
    y = 1:10
)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = function(v) v * 10)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Пытаюсь трансформировать код для оси Y (как и спрашивала)! Мудрёно... Разочарована: подавить все метки, и просто их ... рисовать (вместо того, чтобы они высчитывались из таблицы). И это всё из-за невозможности просто умножить?!

Comment: @Liz_blonde, ну, умножьте, если надо: `plot(c(1:10)*100,ylab="y")`

Comment: Добавил вариант решения с `ggplot2`.

Comment: @Artem Klevtsov ещё раз большое спасибо!

Comment: @aleksandr barakin огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Liz_blonde, если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы