# Изменение оси Y в R

Tags: r

При выполнении кода (см. ниже) по оси Y получаются дроби (0.0, 0.20, 0.40 ... 1.00), а нужны целые числа (0, 20, 40 ... 100) и БЕЗ знака %. Добавление в plot(), напр., опций:`ylim=c(0, 100), yscale=100)`даёт нужное, но при этом кривые рисунка ... совмещаются (нарушается масштаб). Помогите, пожалуйста

```
install.packages("survival")  
install.packages("cmprsk")  
library(survival)  
library(cmprsk) 

time<-c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,32,35,67,68,70,72)  
status<-c(0,1,2,0,2,0,0,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,0,2,1,1,0,0)  
mydata <- data.frame(time, status)  

cumi <- cuminc(time<-mydata$time, status<-mydata$status, (variance=TRUE))  

plot(cumi, las=1, col=1, xlab="Time", ylab="P")
```

Comment: [«просто умножать»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/990582/#comment1671697_990584) тут нечего: «рисует» функция plot.cuminc из пакета cmprsk. в ней разработчками реализован именно вывод долей, а не процентов. так что наиболее простой способ — «просто нарисовать ось y заново».

Comment: Понимаю! Но не получается! Помогите, пожалуйста...

Comment: разбирайтесь с выбранным вами пакетом cmprsk. если создавать объект `Cuminc` (начинается с заглавной) из пакета `mstate`, то там функция печати отлично понимает аргумент `yscale`. например:: `plot(..., yscale=100)`. возможно, в вашем случае надо убрать предел `ylim`

Answer (score 3):

если разработчиками класса не предусмотрено изменение масштаба оси (`xscale` и `yscale`), как в примере с классом `cuminc` из пакета *cmprsk*, значения на шкалах (*labels*) можно нарисовать и самостоятельно.

для начала надо нарисовать график «как есть», чтобы узнать пределы значений по нужной шкале:

```
> plot(cumi, las=1, col=1, xlab="Time", ylab="P")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

видим, что по оси `y` значения — от 0 до 1.

закрываем график и теперь рисуем его заново, отключив предварительно отрисовку шкалы на оси `y` функцией `par()` с соответствующим аргументом:

```
> par(yaxt="n")
> plot(cumi, las=1, col=1, xlab="Time", ylab="P")
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
теперь включаем отрисовку шкалы обратно:

```
> par(yaxt="s")
```

и рисуем шкалу самостоятельно (для иллюстрации я специально сделал шаг значений в два раза меньше, чем на «оригинальном» графике):

```
> axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, 1, 0.1), labels = seq(0, 100, 10), las = 1)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

здесь (см. `?axis`):

- `side` — это сторона (2 — слева)
- `at` — на каких позициях ставить значения
- `labels` — собственно список значений (понятно, что их должно быть ровно столько же, сколько указано и в параметре `at`)
- `las` — стандартный граф. параметр (см. `?par`), задающий ориентацию значений на шкалах

---

дополнение: в принципе, можно обойтись и без вызовов функции `par()`, передавая параметр `yaxt` с нужным значением непосредственно функциям `plot()` и `axis()`:

```
> plot(cumi, las=1, col=1, xlab="Time", ylab="P", yaxt="n")
> axis(side = 2, at = seq(0, 1, 0.1), labels = seq(0, 100, 10), las = 1, yaxt="s")
```

Comment: 1. под более сложным подразумевалось, например, исправление функции `plot.cuminc` из пакета *cmprsk*. 2. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457345/)

Comment: Большое спасибо!